# Can I use Apple Push Notifications in an Cydia application?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, cydia

I have an application with apns to receive push notifications from my server, but my application cannot be posted to iTunes App Store.

And I was thinking if I release this app in Cydia can I still use apns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because apple would eat you alive. However I believe there is a push library for Jailbreak apps on cydia? Just add a dependacy for it when you release your app.